# Cant sort date with Order by Clause

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to use order by clause...

My code...

```
db.rawQuery("select * from pd_data where item_type=1 and item_date like '%" + month + "%' order by date(item_date) DESC Limit 1", null);
```

But this only returns one value...

My date format `dd MMM yyyy`.

How can i resolve this issue..?

Is it possible to sort `dd MMM yyyy` date format using order by clause..?

Comment: try like this db.rawQuery("select * from pd_data where item_type=1 and item_date like '%" + month + "%' order by item_date DESC Limit 1", null);

Comment: If you only get back one result then it has nothing to do with your sorting. Your where-clause reduces it to one result. Are you sure that there are multiple values corresponding to item_type=1 in the month you are checking? And is your database column a date type or a varchar?

Comment: remove `Limit 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The One value returing is due to `Limit 1` at the end of the query.
Try this

```
db.rawQuery("select * from pd_data where item_type=1 and item_date like '%" + month + "%' order by item_date DESC ", null);
```

Answer (score 1):

"This only returns one value", try to remove the `Limit 1` at the end of your query. And yes it is possible to sort your date with the Order By clause.